# How to hide Woocommerce product Description tab only for unlogged users?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

How to hide product "Description" tab' in Woocommerce plugin only for unlogged users, but visible for registered customers *(and logged-in users)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove product description tab on sigle product pages for non logged users, you will use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'customize_product_tabs', 100 );
function customize_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        unset( $tabs['description'] ); // remove the description tab
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```

This code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'customize_product_tabs', 98 ); worked for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add this snippet into the **function.php**

```
add_action( 'init', 'hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );

function hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() { 
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {       

//Remove short description (excerpt) from single product page
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );  
}
}
```

Comment: it's hiding product short description

Comment: how to hide the description tab, which comes next to review tab at the bottom side, please let me know.

Comment: I have updated the answer , replace woocommerce_product_tabs , hope it works.